# Is there a way to reset a select to the option that was selected on load using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Is there a way to reset a select to the option that was selected on load using jquery without having to create a custom cache of the initial value?

Comment: You don't need a "custom cache". A simple variable will do.

Comment: If you don't have any other form elements, just add an `<input type="reset"/>` button to the bottom of the form.

Comment: No, DOM isn't saved anywhere in it's original state.

Comment: What I mean by "custom cache" is storing the value in a variable.  I would prefer to use an object or variable that already has the value stored such as by getting the value off the dom, instead of creating a new one.  Is there an existing method that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As per your comment, updated the code to create custom attr to the select element and use them for reset. See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/XM7xV/2/)** here.

```
//cache all the initial values of the drop down in a custom attr.
$('select').each (function (index) {
    $(this).attr('initial-value', $(this).val());
});

//reset is the button that will be used to reset the value of 
//all the drop down to its initial value.
$('#reset').click (function () {
    $('select').each (function (index) {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('initial-value'));
    });
});
```

Below is the old post which uses a simple javascript variable to save the initial values,

You can cache the initial value in a simple cache and then use them to reset.

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/XM7xV/1/)** here

Answer (score 0):

There is [form.reset](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp) method but it will reset other elements of form as well.

Otherwise put some class on option to identify that option as default.